# Как изменить цвет фона внутри дочернего элемента div при наведении курсора?

Tags: html, css, вёрстка, hover

1. Наведите указатель мыши на `.parent` и  изменяется цвет фона (работает).
2. Наведите указатель мыши на '.child' и  изменяется цвет фона (работает).
3. Я хочу навести курсор на `.child` и изменить только цвет фона `.child`
   Как мне это сделать?

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #cde;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  height: 100px;
}

.parent:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.child {
  float: right;
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.child:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <span class="child">
        Click
    </span>

</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод вопроса [how to change background color inside element of div on hover effect?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51025348/7394871) от участника  [@Aziz Erel](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6322677/aziz-erel).</sub>

Comment: ассоциация:https://stackoverflow.com/q/51025348/7394871

Answer (score 3):

Трюк состоит в том, чтобы создать еще один слой, используя дочерний элемент при наведении курсора, чтобы имитировать неизменность родительского фона.

Вот пример с `box-shadow` ([On hover of child, change background color of parent container (CSS only](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39374918/on-hover-of-child-change-background-color-of-parent-container-css-only)))

```css
.parent {
  background-color: #cde;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  position: relative;
  overflow:hidden;
}

.parent:hover {
  background-color: black;
}

.child {
  position: absolute;
  left: 50%;
  top: 50%;
  padding: 10px;
  background-color: #ff0000;
}

.child:hover {
  background-color: yellow;
  box-shadow:0 0 0 1000px #cde;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

  <span class="child">
        Click
    </span>
</div>
```

<sub>Свободный перевод  [ответа](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51025439/7394871) от участника  [@Temani Afif](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8620333/temani-afif).</sub>

Comment: Саша а кроме того что на кнопке меняется фон, ещё что то должно произойти ? или просто на кнопке меняется фон ?

Comment: @MaximLensky Судя по оригинальному вопросу на EnSO, меняется только фон

Comment: фон кнопки ...?

Comment: @MaximLensky да

Comment: а что не обычного в этом hover ? я просто понять хочу в чём уникальность

Comment: @MaximLensky  "Трюк состоит в том, чтобы создать еще один слой, используя дочерний элемент при наведении курсора, чтобы имитировать неизменность родительского фона."

Comment: ну при наведении на ребенка не возможно изменить родителя ...  либо я не понял фишку вопроса/ ответа

Comment: @MaximLensky Просто сравни работу снипетов в вопросе и ответе